# Jest `clearAllMocks` doesn't seem to "reset" a certain API call `beforeEach`

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am running into an issue where my tests inside a `describe` block aren't getting all API calls reset between tests. If I run an `*.only` test, then the expected `fetch.mock.calls[i]` index changes.

I would have expected each test to have the same number of calls because of the   `beforeEach(jest.clearAllMocks);` block:

```
describe('Account Info', () => {

  beforeEach(jest.clearAllMocks);

  test('edit names', async () => {
    const { findByDisplayValue, findByTestId, getByRole } = render(
      <AccountInfo />,
      {},
      { ...mockGetUserData }
    );
...
    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3));
    expect(fetch.mock.calls[0][1]).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`...`);
  });

  test('edit phone', async () => {
    const { findByTestId, getByRole } = render(
      <AccountInfo />,
      {},
      { ...mockGetUserData }
    );
...
    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2));  // notice it's 2, not 3 like above
    expect(fetch.mock.calls[0][1]).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`...`);

  });
```

This works fine, however, let's say I am working on updating the "edit phone" spec. So I change the test to say `test.only` and now it fails on:

```
    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2));  // notice it's 2, not 3 like above
```

Since now fetch was called `3` times.

It seems that a hook inside the `AccountInfo` component which calls my organization API is the culprit. It's not being cleared, and I don't understand why.

I have resolved the flakiness by putting all the tests into a single spec which is what @kentcdodds [recommends](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/write-fewer-longer-tests), but I'd like to understand more about why Jest might not be resetting as expected.